# Laravel signed route not ignoring complex query parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get a signed URL that accepts complex objects through query parameters. The data must be provided through query parameters because the frontend that will consume the API will use only GET (due to `EventSource`).

Here is an example of the desired URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/endpoint?complex%5B0%5D%5Bfoo%5D=1&complex%5B0%5D%5Bbar%5D=%7B%22value%22%3A+%22one%22%2C+%22lorem%22%3A+%22ipsum+1%22%7D&complex%5B1%5D%5Bfoo%5D=2&complex%5B1%5D%5Bbar%5D=%7B%22value%22%3A+%22two%22%2C+%22lorem%22%3A+%22ipsum+2%22%7D&complex%5B2%5D%5Bfoo%5D=3&complex%5B2%5D%5Bbar%5D=%7B%22value%22%3A+%22three%22%2C+%22lorem%22%3A+%22ipsum+3%22%7D
```

The object in the query parameter is as follows:

```php
'complex' => [
    [
        'foo' => 1,
        'bar' => '{"value": "one", "lorem": "ipsum 1"}',
    ],
    [
        'foo' => 2,
        'bar' => '{"value": "two", "lorem": "ipsum 2"}',
    ],
    [
        'foo' => 3,
        'bar' => '{"value": "three", "lorem": "ipsum 3"}',
    ],
]
```

The signed url was generated to the version without parameters using `URL::signedRoute()`, so I would add the `complex` query parameter to the URL `http://localhost:8000/endpoint?signature=123` and expect that it is ignored in the validation step.

I am avoiding using a custom middleware because each controller method that handles signed routes will specify which parameters to ignore, so middlewares may not be dynamic enough to me.

Using `request()->hasValidSignatureWhileIgnoring(['complex'])` has not worked. I would like to know if I am missing something or if the method `hasValidSignatureWhileIgnoring` can't handle such query parameters.

---

Environment Info:

```
Laravel Version .......................... 9.52.15  
PHP Version .............................. 8.1.27
```

Comment: well the thing is that you don't have a `complex` param in your url. You have a `complex[0][foo]`, `complex[0][bar]` and so on